# Django user interacition with other users?

Tags: django, web

In a Django web app, let's say there is a prediction cast by the user Daniel. In the prediction, there is an accept button, any User can accept this prediction.

What I want to know is that if User Andrew accepts the offer, how can I store that in Daniel's prediction class? (If there is an accepted_by field in Daniel's prediction class, how can I change that field to Andrew, the actual User object not just a string, when User Andrew accepts that prediction)?

Thanks

In my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class gamble(models.Model):
    prediction = models.BooleanField()
    placement = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    accepted_by = models. **# this is what I need help with**
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)



def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('page-home')
```

Comment: can more than one user accept a prediction?

Comment: basically, you need a view that accepts the prediction and updates the field with the current user. Care to show your models?

Comment: @AMG, No, only one user can accept. And I shared my models.py, not sure if that is what is needed :)

Comment: `accepted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="accepter")`

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name for some more

Comment: @AMG, hey mate! With my limited knowledge in django, do you think this is a possible fix: I am displaying my home page (where all the predictions will be shown in) with a createview. Createviews can accept context, so if I pass in the current user browsing as the context... Now do I have access to the current user?

Comment: @AMG, oh , I just saw your post, thanks man!

Comment: if you are using the AuthenticationMiddleware middleware you'll already have request.user available to you (no need to specify in the context)